# How to call a python script from MySQL DB (iOS)

Tags: python, ios, mysql

I have an iOS app that is connecting to a MySQL db. At one point I am authenticating the users information. Doing some research informs me that the safest way to do this is by doing so server side. How would I go about calling a python script from MySQL and returning it?

Comment: Just to be clear: Your iOS app is *direcly* connecting to the database?

Comment: yes. it is directly connecting to the database.

Comment: Assuming the database is on a remote machine and not running on the iOS device, that is not a good idea.

Comment: Instead of an `INSERT` trigger setup a `SELECT` trigger, but it looks like its frowned upon See: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54989/in-sql-server-how-to-launch-a-python-script-from-an-insert-trigger And: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html The returned data might have to be inserted into the database? I didn't see anything related to returning data from a trigger. Again to reiterate. It appears to be a security issue and a no no.